# Canon IP4200 driver not working

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, printing, canon, pixma

Any Ideas how to setup a IP4200with Ubuntu 12.04 64bit?

As far as I know, there is no official driver by canon.

http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu oneiric is not working

Hope somebody can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To install this Canon printer driver for Ubuntu you need to add the PPA below in your Ubuntu system. Open a "terminal" window and copy and paste these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon
sudo apt-get update
```

Make sure to disconnect the Canon printer from your computer first.

Now copy and paste your appropriate install command based on your printer:

```
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-ip4200series
```

After the Canon printer driver is installed, connect the Canon printer to your computer and turn it on. Your printer will automatically be detected by the system.

[source](http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2012/02/install-canon-printer-for-ubuntu-linux.html)